# How can I set the mouse position in a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

I have a 3d rendering program that rotates the world around an observer based on the position the mouse is on the screen. The amount in radians that the world is rotated is defined by this line

```
    glob.worldx=-(w.winfo_pointerxy()[0]-xy[0])/250
```

Where xy[0] is the x coordinate of the center of the screen

This means that the amount that the observers field of view can be rotated is limited by the distance the mouse can go. If I could get the mouse to come back to the center of the screen I could solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of moving the pointer, perhaps make the position of the pointer control the *speed* with which the world rotates -- the farther from center the faster the rotation.

Comment: That is a great suggestion unetbu, and I used to use that control scheme, but it is not as user friendly as I wanted it to be, so I want something similar to how a first person shooter game is controlled

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The good news is that there is a way to do it.

The intermediate news is that it's not well documented.

The bad news is that it only works on some platforms.

The other intermediate news is that you can step outside of Tk on at least some platforms.

---

The way to do this in Tcl/Tk is by generating a `<Motion>` event with `-warp 1`. The documentation on this is sparse, and scattered around a few different pages (start at [`bind`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm)), but the details are described [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1689). Basically, it's just this:

```
event generate . <Motion> -warp 1 -x 50 -y 50
```

So, how do you do this from Tkinter?

Well, `event_generate` isn't documented anywhere, and neither is the `<Motion>` event, or the `warp` parameter… but it's pretty simple to figure out if you know how Tk maps to Tkinter:

```
window.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=50, y=50)
```

And this does indeed generate an event, as you can see by binding `<Motion>`. Here's a simple test program:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    root.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=50, y=50)

def motion(event):
    print('motion {}, {}'.format(event.x, event.y))

root.bind('<Key>', key)
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
root.mainloop()
```

Run it, click the window to make sure it has focus, move the cursor around, and you'll see it print out something like this:

```
motion 65, 69
motion 65, 70
motion 65, 71
```

Then hit a key, and it'll print out this:

```
motion 50, 50
```

Which is great… except that it may not actually be able to move your cursor, in which case all this does is trick Tk into thinking the cursor moved.

---

From skimming various forums, it looks like:

- Mac: Does not work.

  - You must have Tk 8.6.something or later (see [issue 2926819](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2926819&group_id=12997&atid=112997)). And you [probably have 8.5.something](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/).
  - But it's not hard to go right to the Cocoa API.
- Windows: Usually works.

  - You must have Tk 8.4.something or later. I couldn't find the bug for this, but you can count on 8.4 with any official Windows binary install of Python 2.7 or 3.x+.
  - You also must not be running a full-screen app (which you generally aren't, with Tk).
  - On Vista and later, in some cases it won't work. This may have something to do with not owning the desktop session or not being a local console session, or it may have to do with needing Administrator or other privileges.
  - If it doesn't work, it's easy to go right to the Win32 API.
- X11 (most linux, *BSD, etc.): Usually

  - Your window manager must not have disabled other clients from warping the pointer. Fortunately, that doesn't seem to be a common thing to do.
  - If you have this problem, there's no way around it.
- Other platforms (iOS, Android, etc.): No idea.

For Mac, you want to generate and send an [`NSMouseMoved`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html) event. The easy way to do this is with `pyobjc` (which is built in if you're using Apple's Python; otherwise you have to install it):

```
app = Foundation.NSApplication.sharedApplication()
event = Foundation.NSEvent.mouseEventWithType_location_modifierFlags_timestamp_windowNumber_context_eventNumber_clickCount_pressure_(
    Foundation.NSMouseMoved, (50, 50), 0, 0,
    app.mainWindow().windowNumber(), None, 0, 0, 0.0)
app.sendEvent_(event)
```

For Windows, you want to call the [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, or generate and send a MOUSEEVENT. The former will not work with, e.g., DirectX games; the latter may not work with remote desktops. For this case, you probably want the former. Either way, the easiest way to do this is to install [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/), and then it's just:

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((50, 50))
```

Comment: @Tim: Great! I did a bit more research; let me update things.

Comment: Works like a charm abernart! Is there a way I can do this without pressing a key? the closest I have gotten is by putting the root.event_generate function in the mouse motion event, but that updates pretty slowly

Comment: Never mind, I just plopped the event_generate in a while loop and it worked, thanks for everything!

Comment: @sam: You can call the `event_generate` function from anywhere you want; I just bound it to `<Key>` just to make it easy to test. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: OK, I found out (most of) the details for Windows and Mac and updated the answer.

Comment: On my Linux box (RHEL 6.7 and Gnome) to place mouse pointer inside a canvas widget, one extra step to take is to offset canvas.winfo_pointerxy() with canvas.winfo_rootx() and winfo_rooty() before passing the desired coordinates to canvas.envent_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=newX, y=newY). Apparently canvas.winfor_pointerxy() is relative to canvas's parent, not within the canvas itself.

Comment: TheLizzard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808226/6929343) seems to work perfectly in Linux (ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested in moving the cursor to an absolute position on the screen (using @abarnert's tkinter method):

```py
# Moves the mouse to an absolute location on the screen
def move_mouse_to(x, y):
    # Create a new temporary root
    temp_root = tk.Tk()
    # Move it to +0+0 and remove the title bar
    temp_root.overrideredirect(True)
    # Make sure the window appears on the screen and handles the `overrideredirect`
    temp_root.update()
    # Generate the event as @abarnert did
    temp_root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp=True, x=x, y=y)
    # Make sure that tcl handles the event
    temp_root.update()
    # Destroy the root
    temp_root.destroy()
```

This function shouldn't interfere with other tkinter windows. Please note that this function creates a new window that is refreshed twice so it might be slow and the user might notice the window created.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. Glad to be the first upvote :)