# How to hide or disable the mouse pointer in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

I have a fullscreen Tkinter Python application which does not need the mouse -- a simplified version is below. It opens fullscreen and activates a text widget upon pressing `F1`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.root.configure(background='red')
        self.root.bind('<F1>', self.opennote)
        self.root.bind('<F2>', self.closenote)
        self.root.bind('<F3>', self.quit)
        l = tk.Label(text="some text here")
        l.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def opennote(self, event):
        self.n = tk.Text(self.root, background='blue')
        self.n.pack()

    def closenote(self, event):
        self.n.destroy()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.root.destroy()

App()
```

When launched, the mouse pointer is not visible. It becomes visible, though, after initiating the Text widget, and then stays (changing shape between the text frame and the rest of the screen).

I found several articles about how to hide a mouse cursor (by using `cursor=''` in parameters) but I did not find anything which would work for the mouse pointer across the widgets.

Is it possible to completely hide (or disable) the mouse pointer in Tkinter?

([a question on how to set the mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704032/how-can-i-set-the-mouse-position-in-a-tkinter-window) helped me to move this cursor away by issuing a `self.root.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), y=self.root.winfo_screenheight())`. This is not a solution but at least the pointer does not jump in one's face from the middle of the screen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can come is to create a `Frame` and set the cursor to 'none', but it still has an issue of requiring the cursor to leave and re-enter the app window, at least on my machine (Mac OS X Mavericks). Maybe someone else can figure out how to trigger the cursor to disappear when the application loads, but here's the code I have so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.main_frame.config(background='red', cursor='none')
        self.main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self.root.bind('<F1>', self.opennote)
        self.root.bind('<F2>', self.closenote)
        self.root.bind('<F3>', self.quit)
        l = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="some text here")
        l.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def opennote(self, event):
        self.n = tk.Text(self.main_frame, background='blue')
        self.n.pack()

    def closenote(self, event):
        self.n.destroy()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.root.destroy()

App()
```

Answer (score 36):

I guess,

`root.config(cursor="none")` should work.

Comment: Worked for me under both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16

Comment: Works great for main cursor, still shows when selecting on an Entry textbox though. Edit, have to add this .config to the Entry as well to hide it there. Maybe there is a way to apply to all children of root using a loop, not sure how to account for new children being added though... can an event be binded to root for this purpose?