# Set mouse coordinates to 0,0 with Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to program a touchscreen keypad on my PiTFT display.
I have disabled the visibility of the mouse with **root.config(cursor='none')** however even though it is not visible it is inevitably hovering over a button at the most inappropriate times.
What code could I use to send the mouse cursor to position 0,0?
Googling this seemed to provide some insane operations to achieve such a simple function. What did I miss?

As always, thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have you checked this question? [How can I set the mouse position in a tkinter window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704032/how-can-i-set-the-mouse-position-in-a-tkinter-window)

Comment: That link is what I initially found before I made this post. I was a little intimidated when I started reading RADIANS and such and skipped over the thread. However, now I read it over a few times and at the end I found the nugget of information I was looking for. Thanks! It seems that "root.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=5, y=5)" works for me. However I cannot get it to work on program start-up. Any idea why it gets ignored in the main body of the program? I have placed this within a touchscreen function that is called frequently and it does make the cursor go away after first press.